# Problem with docker volume inside docker compose with java socket used

Tags: java, docker, sockets, websocket, docker-compose

I have problem with sending files through socket while everything is inside of docker compose containers (my program works normally on localhost).

So my applicattion contains:

- client
- API GATEWAY
- microservices
- file server

Of course I have problem with the last one. Below I will show errors I get and my code.

Does this code create file inside container?

```
File directory = new File("pliki");
if (!directory.exists()) {
    directory.mkdir();
}

String fileName = message.split("#")[1].split(":")[1];
File file = new File("pliki/" + fileName);
```

Docker compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
 users_db:
  image: mysql:latest
  volumes:
   - "./.mysql-data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
 restart: always
 ports:
  - "3306:3306"
 environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
  MYSQL_DATABASE: users
  MYSQL_USER: czarek
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123
registration:
 image: register
 links:
  - users_db
 depends_on:
  - users_db
login:
 image: login
 links:
  - users_db
 depends_on:
  - users_db
chat:
 image: chat
 links:
  - users_db
 depends_on:
  - users_db
table:
 image: table
 links:
  - users_db
 depends_on:
  - users_db
 fileserver:
 image: fileserver
 volumes:
  - fileServer:/pliki
server:
 image: api
 ports:
  - "1000:1000"
 links:
  - login
  - fileserver
  - registration
  - chat
  - table
volumes:
 fileServer:
```

To sum up I know that problem is inside of this code or my docker compose file is wrong.

Comment: Can you reduce what you've shown to a [mcve]?  There's a lot of code here; what of it really matters?  Can you show the error message as plain text and not a PNG file, and if it's a "connection reset" error, what are you trying to connect to and from where?  Also please make sure the indentation is correct in the `docker-compose.yml` file, and delete obsolete options like `links:`.

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't really know if I made it clear. I will say shortly here. I want to transfer file throgh sockets in docker but while I send it i can't see files in docker desktop. ++ If i will delete links from docker compose it will still work or i need to change it to something